# How to get selected date from ionic-2 calendar onchange() method

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, momentjs, angular-calendar

I am using ion2-calendar.

this is my html:

```
 <ion-calendar [(ngModel)]="date"
              (onChange)="onChange($event)"
              [type]="type"
              [format]="'YYYY-MM-DD'">
</ion-calendar>
```

and this is onchange in ts:

```
onChange($event) {

      console.log("onchange event called");
      console.log(moment().format('DD-MM-YYYY'));  
    }
```

This is my console:

```
onSelect event called
25-06-2018
```

But i am always getting current month and year,no matter which date I choose. Only the date value is changing.
Its showing current month and year in the console for all dates.
Can someone tell me how to get selected date in dd-mm-yy format from $event object.

Edit- This is what i get for `console.log($event)`

[image]

```
Moment {_isAMomentObject: true, _i: 1530297000000, _isUTC: false, _pf: {…}, _locale: Locale, …}
_d
:
Sat Jun 30 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) {}
_i
:
1530297000000
_isAMomentObject
:
true
_isUTC
:
false
_isValid
:
true
_locale
:
Locale {_calendar: {…}, _longDateFormat: {…}, _invalidDate: "Invalid date", ordinal: ƒ, _dayOfMonthOrdinalParse: /\d{1,2}(th|st|nd|rd)/, …}
_pf
:
{empty: false, unusedTokens: Array(0), unusedInput: Array(0), overflow: -2, charsLeftOver: 0, …}
__proto__
:
Object
```

It shows correct date of click.
It would be great if someone could tell me how to extract date from this .

Comment: What happens when you add console.log($event) in onChange

Comment: Moment {_isAMomentObject: true, _i: 1530210600000, _isUTC: false, _pf: {…}, _locale: Locale, …}
_d
:
Fri Jun 29 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) {}
_i
:
1530210600000
_isAMomentObject
:
true
_isUTC
:
false
_isValid
:
true
_locale
:
Locale {_calendar: {…}, _longDateFormat: {…}, _invalidDate: "Invalid date", ordinal: ƒ, _dayOfMonthOrdinalParse: /\d{1,2}(th|st|nd|rd)/, …}
_pf
:
{empty: false, unusedTokens: Array(0), unusedInput: Array(0), overflow: -2, charsLeftOver: 0, …}
__proto__
:
Object

@BerkAkkerman

Comment: cant you use `this.date` in onChange function? `console.log(moment().format('DD-MM-YYYY')); ` doesnt access `this.date` at all...  you are simply creating a new date object

Comment: @SurajRao this.date gives me undefined in log.

Comment: try `ngModelChange()` instead of onChange event...

Comment: @SurajRao Error- Can't bind to 'ngModelChange()' since it isn't a known property of 'ion-calendar

Comment: @SurajRao I have added new log details in question, plz check.

Comment: Did you try to change type of your calender from controller. type = 'js-date' or type = 'string'

Comment: Its already a moment object.

Comment: I think, this is what you want : console.log($event.format('DD-MM-YYYY'))

Comment: @BerkAkkerman Thank you, the exact one-liner that I was looking for.

Comment: @BerkAkkerman if you could post it as answer i will mark it as closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$event` of `OnChange()` is a moment object.

you can format like this: `$event.format('DD-MM-YYYY')`

Answer (score 2):

`moment()` statement always generates **current time** like `new Date()`.

you should use a statement like `moment("1995-12-25")` or other various statements.

For details, please have a look at this [moment.js docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/)

---

**update**

To say the conclusion first,

**.html** (nothing changed)

```
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-calendar [(ngModel)]="date"
  (onChange)="onChange($event)"
  [type]="type"
  [format]="'YYYY-MM-DD'">
</ion-calendar>
```

**.ts**

```
onChange(event) {
  console.log(event.format('DD-MM-YYYY')); // For actual usage.
  console.log(moment(event).format('DD-MM-YYYY')); // the statement you might think about
}
```

the above code gives you what you want.

What I want to say is that you should not use `moment()` but `moment(event)`. Because `moment()` returns **moment instance** which has **current time** while `moment(event)` returns **moment instance** which has the time `event` carries.

Comment: I dont understand how is your answer related to my onchange method of calendar.
I need to access the date that is selected. I don't know how to do that and that is my question.

Comment: I think its still not quite correct? `event` already is a moment object. Can you pass it again into `moment` function?

Comment: @SurajRao, you are right. Actually, we don't need to **pass moment to moment** again. For my thought, the reason @Nabil could not debug by himself is caused from misunderstanding about usage of `moment()`. So, I just wanna point out that.  And event can change its own types up to `[type]`, I might add. I will modify my anwser clearly upon your adivce.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the Release Candidate version changed the output event to change instead of onChange and select instead of onSelect. Try using this:

`<ion-calendar [(ngModel)]="date"
(change)="onChange($event)"`
[format]="'YYYY-MM-DD'">
`

Answer (score -2):

```
<ion-calendar [(ngModel)]="date" (change)="onChange($event)"  [type]="type" 
   [format]="'YYYY-MM-DD'">
</ion-calendar>
    
date;
type: "string";
onChange(event) {
    console.log(moment(this.date._d).format("YYYY-MM-DD"));
}
```